# Is it an automatic crit if I hit with an extended threat range?

Tags: critical-hit, attack-roll, 13th-age

In 13th Age, like most D20 variants, you can have items or abilities that improve your crit range. However, in 13th Age, a natural 20 is a automatic crit hit (if I am not mistaken, you do not need to check if you hit). What is unclear to me if say I have +2 Crit Range (18-20), is it an automatic hit if I roll a 18, or do I is that just a threat and I need to roll to see if I hit?

Updated with the rules (pg 196 of the Escalation V6 version)

> Every attack roll that is a natural 20 is a crit ('critical hit') for double damage.

And that's all it says. Here's the part on crit range:

> Each point of improvement in crit range drops the number needed to score a critical hit by 1.

Comment: Does the game say *anywhere* that confirmation is necessary? Are you just assuming "crit confirmation" is a thing that exists in the system because it is a thing in d20?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) you *threaten* a critical hit on a natural roll within your ***threat* range**, and it needs to be confirmed to become an actual critical hit by re-rolling the attack die (the "critical roll") and scoring a hit. ([d20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#criticalHits))

In [13th-age](/questions/tagged/13th-age), per your citations, you have a ***crit* range** instead, and you automatically score a critical hit on a natural roll within this range. There is no need to confirm.

In your case, if you roll a natural 18 on an attack with a weapon with an 18-20 crit range, you may roll for double damage.

Answer (score 0):

A critical double damage (pg 167 core book).  However, I don't see anything that says that all criticals are automatic hits.  By a strict reading, this could lead to a case with an expanded crit range and a hard to hit opponent where a roll could be a critical but also a miss.  So it would in that case double the miss damage.

With a less strict reading, the rules call out a 20 as a "critical hit", and the rules do imply some familiarity with other d20 games for basic concepts.  Having any critical as a hit would be a defendable position.  This could be supported that while there are rules for 20 as auto-success for skills (something not true in some popular d20 games), there are no rules that say that a 20 attack is an auto-hit, just an assumption that it is.

Comment: Dunno about that reasoning. You can't "score a critical hit" if you miss.